# Can I determine the current IP from a known MAC Address?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a shell script which uses etherwake to wake up a machine on my local network.
After the machine is awake, I'm not sure of the IP address.

While trying to answer my own question I came up with:

```
ip=$(ping -c 1 hostname | head -1 | awk '{print $3}' | sed 's/[()]//g')
```

This solution stipulates that I know the hostname of the remote machine, which isn't so onerous.

Is there a way to get the IP if all I know is the MAC address?

Comment: if you know the host name, resolve it's ip, the same way you'd resolve any other host name. And to note, the ping command first calls gethostbyname in it's code, to resolve the ip of the hostname.

Comment: You can do a RARP if you are on the same switch/hub/crossover cabal as the system with the known MAC address

Comment: @ahmad : It looks like arping is a convenient way to get MAC for a known IP. I'm not seeing that it can work the other way.

Comment: @johnathon : Pursuing this question has led me to the conclusion that knowing the hostname can lead to everything else. 
gethostip -- hostname => IP
arping -- hostname => IP and MAC

Comment: possible duplicate of [resolving mac address for IP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480689/resolving-mac-address-for-ip)

Comment: An other option is to configure the router to reverve a specific ip address for that mac address. That's how I solved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know is old, but the simplest way in linux is:

```
arp -a | grep "00:1E:C9:56:3C:8E"
```

The point of this is to ignore if is connected in one or another network meanwhile each device can see each other.

Answer (score 51):

I don't think there is a single command to do this. One hack would be to do a ping scan or a broadcast ping on the subnet and then query the arp table for the IP address of the MAC address. Obviously not an ideal solution. Example:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 >/dev/null && arp -an | grep <mac address here> | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[()]//g'
```

Here nmap will do a ping scan and populate your arp cache. Once the scan is done, the arp command can be used to print the arp table and then you pull out the IP address with grep/awk. You could try replacing nmap with a broadcast ping, but that probably isn't as reliable.

Comment: This achieves what I set out to do. Thanks!

After all of the above, I'm thinking it's not unreasonable that my program just use the remote machine's hostname.

Comment: When you have a very large network, e.g.  /16 subnet this takes too long  :(

Comment: Doens't work for me. `arp -an` outputs just 4 some random addresses, and `nmap ...` doesn't change that.

Comment: Why not just use arp alone? For me ip=$(arp -a | grep $mac | awk '{print $2}'  | sed 's/[()]//g') works.

Comment: @ThomasDevoogdt , sometimes (depending on your network traffic) the ARP cache is not populated enough, and does not include the MAC address you are searching for.

Comment: How should I run this if I only know `192.168`? is it `192.168.0.0/255/24`?

Comment: In case someone else stumbles upon this, you could try do a broadcast ping i.e. in linux either:

ping -c 1 -w 1 -b 192.168.x.255
OR
ping -c 1 -w 1 -b -I <LAN-INTERFACE> 255.255.255.255

Then wait a few seconds to check the arp table

Answer (score 38):

I would simply use

```
ip neighbor | grep -i "00:1E:C9:56:3C:8E" | cut -d" " -f1
```

Comment: This worked last night, but not today. What? I had to run `nmap -sP xxx.xxx.xxx.0/24` before this command, then it worked again

Comment: I think it just checks the ARP cache.

Comment: This is the right way in a modern GNU/Linux box. Further info: [`man ip-neighbour`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-neighbour.8.html)

Comment: super, but remember the MAC is case sensitive (gentoo)

Comment: @caligari that doesn't even show the complete list. There are a couple of IPs that are not listed and I'm absolutely sure they are there.

Comment: @DnD use ```grep -i``` (Please, @hanoo Can you improve the answer with insensitive grepping?)

Comment: @m4l490n man page says _The IPv4 neighbour table is also known by another name - the ARP table._ Probably, missing hosts are not in the ARP table: try to send a packet (ping?) before the command.

Answer (score 15):

The other methods presented here were unreliable, e.g. the output of `ip neighbor` did not always contain the most recent state, so I ended up re-scanning the network using `arp-scan`, and hence I simply used the output of the scanning to obtain the IP address for a given MAC address.

For scanning a single network interface, simply use this:

```
arp-scan -q -l --interface en4 2>/dev/null | grep "00:1E:C9:56:3C:8E" | cut -d$'\t' -f1
```

The following command scans multiple network interfaces at once:

```
{ arp-scan -q -l --interface en0 2>/dev/null & arp-scan -q -l --interface en4 2>/dev/null } | grep "00:1E:C9:56:3C:8E" | cut -d$'\t' -f1
```

Comment: I've used: `sudo arp-scan --localnet` . Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You could try the arp command and grep by mac address

```
arp -a | grep "00:00:00:00:00:00"
```

(replace with your own mac addr)

Comment: what if two interfaces with different networks and 2 different ip records for each one? Which one is active one?

Comment: arp -a only shows what is in cache. So you need to use arp-scan or nmap first. Also, see comment above.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a python module that can do this:

```
>>> from ethip import ethip
>>> print ethip.getip('00:1E:C9:56:3C:8E', '10.5.42.255')
10.5.42.3
```

I just makes rapid arp requests to find the ip, then caches what it finds. The code is on github.

Comment: `ethip.getip('00:1E:C9:56:3C:8E', '10.5.42.255')` gives an `EOFError` with no information on the ARP. Once ARP has the details of the device under question,  `ethip.getip()` works fine. Is there a way to get the ip address without having to update the ARP table everytime

Comment: @Blue it has to be run with root privileges. You need root to send an arp request, afaik

Comment: python2 and no longer maintained

Answer (score 1):

[Neal's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13553111/5480836) answer takes indeed too long. I had to get it work with a 60k+ IPs range. The trick to make this work is to check arp table after each ping. This also fixes the root problem : no need. I did it in Java (see [threadedScan() here](https://gitlab.com/eaz/VMLauncher/blob/master/src/comp/src/liv/utils/NetworkUtils.java#L72)) because I was on windows and needed a solution which wouldn't spawn thousands of cmd prompts while trying to ping with start command. And it works faster (~10 sec for my 60k range) with a fixedThreadPool.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because 60k+ in a single broadcast domain is a bad idea.