# Get IP Address from Mac Address

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to determine a device's IP address from its MAC address over a local network?  If possible, I'd like to be able to do this from the command line.

I need to connect my raspberry pi to my school wireless network and ssh/vnc into it, but I don't want to have to bring peripherals ( mouse, keyboard, monitor ) just to check which IP address it's been dynamically allocated.

Comment: If you are in the same network you can use "fping" to ping all the subnet (eg 192.168.1.0/24) and then use "arp -a" to retrieve the IPAdress from the Mac. But it would be easier with a fixed ip adress for the Rpi

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I determine the current IP from a known MAC Address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13552881/can-i-determine-the-current-ip-from-a-known-mac-address)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) protocol.

First get the broadcast address of your LAN (you can find that out using:

```
ifconfig
```

Then ping that address in order to refresh the ARP table of the system. (All neighbours will answer)

```
ping -b -c1 BROADCAST_IP_ADDRESS
```

Now you can use arp -a and look for the IP address:

```
arp -a
```

You may automate this using

```
arp -a | grep MAC_ADRESS | cut -f2 | tr -d '()'
```

Comment: Trying the second line returns 'bad option' for -b and -c1.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a utility like airodump-ng or wireshark to scan for the mac address and get the IP that way.

Alternatively look at `ARP -a`

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is for you to use the RARP protocol. This seems to be deprecated and might not be enabled in the TCP/IP stack of your Raspberry. Tweak a little with your Raspi configuration to see if you can enable it. Then, from another Linux box, you can issue the command `rarp -a`

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post, but I needed this recently.

I've tried to ping all devices on local network, this represented 65k+ different ip addresses. I somehow managed to launch the pings in parralel in batch with start command, but with so much commands it quickly gets a mess of command prompts opening and closing, and seem to be bad enough for my laptop.

Then, I tried with java and its isReachable() method, which tries a ping. Enclosed this on a fixed thread pool and here i go again... pings done, arp -a gives me the IP.... i try a second time, arp-a gives nothing... wtf

The VERY IMPORTANT thing, if you want to scan your network, is to check your arp table for your wanted IP after EACH ping. In Java I managed to scan all 60k+ ip addresses in like 30secs, and couldn't do better with batch... because yeah, I had to do it in windows

Hope it'll help somebody...

Comment: Now, do that for a default `/64` IPv6 network, which has `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` possible addresses. At the apparent rate of 2000 addresses per second that you observed, it will take you over `292,271,023` years!

Comment: Yeah well, interesting, but its on IPv4, and this answers the question asked, for which I had found no complete answer. The 30sec is relative to the number of threads the system could handle. so if your system could handle 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 threads or some big fraction of this, it could be faster. Even on my own system I limited the number of threads at 200. So what's the point here? Do you know a better way to reliably find an IP address knowing the machne's MAC address?

Answer (score 0):

Using ifconfig command

```
  ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1
```

Just by using  `ifconfig` gives a whole list of details , inorder to filter to the right ip address. Use grep inet to narrow your search.

Here -v means "Invert the sense of matching". Avoid lines having keyword `127.0.0.1` in the search criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a powershell script that does this, came to this forum and a number of other forums when I was researching (works on windows, if you
can translate from ps to batch it should work on both, windows batch is mostly the same as linux batch, just a few syntax differences):

```
<# enter subnet range here#>
$iprange = 100..250

<#ping address range- this forces an addition of the connected device to 
 the arp table#>
Foreach ($ip in $iprange)
{
  $computer = "192.168.1.$ip"
  ping $computer
}

$mac="Put Mac address here"
$ip=arp -a | select-string $mac |% { $_.ToString().Trim().Split(" ")[0] }

"$mac has an ip of $ip"
```