# How to get remote host MAC address by using its ip address in c programming in linux

Tags: c, linux, macos, ip-address, remote-host

Can some one tell me, how to get remote host MAC address  by using its  ip address in linux by using c programming(could be netlink sockets or BSD sockets)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the MAC address of the remote host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092463/getting-the-mac-address-of-the-remote-host)

Comment: The question above is for c#, but you can't do it anyway (without sending actual ARP or NDisc requests), so it's related.

Comment: You can get only MAC addresses of computers on your local network.

Comment: The local network MACs are listed in `/proc/net/arp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done using C programming. If it was possible then there wouldn't be any protocol like `ARP` to get the link layer address.

You can implement ARP request and reply using socket programming. But that's not what you want in this case I think. Anyway in that case you can refer to this discussion
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710040/arp-request-and-reply-using-c-socket-programming).

**You can have a look at this for that purpose** [source code](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.opensource.apple.com%2Fsource%2Fnetwork_cmds%2Fnetwork_cmds-307.0.1%2Farp.tproj%2Farp.c&ei=Jkw2VfSTHMa2mAXi74HICA&usg=AFQjCNFBrhDrfK0V6tmaE4Tqf-NJatKPdw&bvm=bv.91071109,d.dGY).

Comment: True,Can we make use of ARP, Is there any direct way to initiate  an ARP request to get the remote host MAC address ?

Comment: @linuxman.: check the link provided. you will get clear idea.