# how to find client info in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webpage, and people come to vote there.
but I want everyone to send just one vote!
please help me with c# code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple different approaches you can take.

**One** approach would be to log everyone's ip address. The problem with this is many people are behind routers. If you prevent users from voting by ip address then you could be blocking people who haven't voted yet.

A **second** approach is to require the user to login. This is the surest way to prevent users from voting more than once. It's also the most involved. You can cut a lot of work out by using the ASP.NET membership provider.

A **third** approach is to set a cookie on the user's computer. They can easily delete the cookie, but most users don't know they are there and don't really care.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky one and I'm pretty sure that you'll have to make a trade-off in some way.

1. Check the IP as in [how to find client info in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598828/how-to-find-client-info-in-asp-net/1598851#1598851) and HTTP_FORWARDED the problem is that any IP is easily spoofed and two people can use the same computer and/or have dynamic IP:s
2. Send an email with a confirmation
3. The user must register in your system
4. Require an OpenId

I'd go for number 4

Answer (score 1):

Get the IP using this statement.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

When People vote, Store IP in database and check 2nd time they came

OR

You can store some information in client cookie and check for the 2nd time

Answer (score 0):

Get the MAC address from the remote machine, and keep track of that.

[want to get mac address of remote PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092379/want-to-get-mac-address-of-remote-pc)

However, this would be more complicated in C# as I'm reasonably sure you can't do that using .NET since you'd need to use [ManagementObjects](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=7188), which probably won't work.

However, if you are doing this from asp.net, you can do the Java thing, by embedding it in the asp.net page, and calling it when necessary.

Comment: LIX needs a C# solution not Java applet one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple and reliable solution just use the [Cookie mechanism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

First you have to try to read the Cookie: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287533%28VS.71%29.aspx

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
myCookie = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"];

if (myCookie != null)
  //User has already voted.
else
  //User can vote.
```

If the cookie does not exists you allow voting, after vote you just write a cookie in a response: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287547%28VS.71%29.aspx.

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```