# Finding the MAC address of the sender of a multicast UDP message in Python?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, multicast, mac-address

I have some code that listens for "announcements" via UDP multicast. I can get the IP address of the sender, but what I really need is the MAC address of the sender (since the IP address can and will change).

Is there an easy way to do this in Python?

A code snippet is included for reference, but likely unnecessary.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

# Allow multiple sockets to use the same PORT number
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind to the port that we know will receive multicast data
sock.bind((self.interface, MCAST_PORT))

# Tell API we are a multicast socket
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 255)

# Tell API we want to add ourselves to a multicast group
# The address for the multicast group is the third param

status = sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, 
          socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, 
          socket.inet_aton(MCAST_ADDR) + socket.inet_aton(self.interface));

data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
```

...

Comment: It should be possible with `scapy`'s L2 sockets though may require some work: http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot, in general, get the mac address. You might succeed using ARP on a LAN, but across the Internet it's not possible.

Consider the case where the packet you receive has the IP address of the sender's [NATting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) router. The packet may have traversed any number of intermediate machines along the way, each of which have mac addresses, too. Whose responsibility should it be to support the kind of lookup you're after? For all the machines along the way, the sender's mac address is completely useless, so why bother supporting that kind of lookup?

And, btw, [changing the mac address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_spoofing) is trivial on many network cards, so using it as some kind of unique ID is not a wise idea.

Comment: Say I don't want to get the MAC of the original sender, but the "Source MAC" of the Ethernet packet that transports the UDP packet. Is it possible using standard Linux facilities? At least I can get this information in Wireshark on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to capture the raw Ethernet frame, not just the UDP packet.

```
import socket

ETH_P_ALL=3
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL))
sock.bind((interface_name, 0))
data = sock.recv(2000)
dmac = data[:6]
smac = data[6:12]
udp_offset = 14
ethertype = data[12:14]
if ethertype == [0x81, 0x00]: # 802.1Q VLAN-tagged
    udp_offset += 4
udp_pkt = data[udp_offset:]
```

Some notes:

- An Ethertype value of 0x88a8 would indicate 802.1ad QinQ or "stacked VLAN" and would need to be handled appropriately to correctly find the UDP data.
- On most Linux systems you need to be `root` (or have the `CAP_NET_RAW` capability) to do this.  Not sure what you need on Windows, but assume something similar.
- In practice this will be something of a firehose as it will receive **all** UDP packets.  You can either parse the UDP header yourself to narrow it down to the ones you are interested in, or (on Linux / BSD etc) investigate Berkeley Packet Filter to get the kernel to do it for you.  The latter is much more CPU efficient but is rather a pain to implement.
- Answers suggesting ARP or similar might do what you want but they might not.  They will tell you what association your OS has between IP addresses and MACs; this won't help for layer 2 protocols, multicast, broadcast etc or if something is lying in response to ARP requests.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol you need is [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol). Check this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85577/search-for-host-with-mac-address-using-python) for details

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that it is possible to get the sender's MAC address since the MAC address is a link level address and not a network level address like IP. The MAC address will change at each hop in the network as the packet containing the UDP message is routed from the sender to the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it in python but it is possible to get MAC address. For example by using tcpdump I put all packets into file:

```
sudo tcpdump -i enp0s31f6 -w file_name port 6665
```

then in python read it with:

```
       packetlist = rdpcap("./file_name")
       for pkt in packetlist:  
       print pkt.src, pkt.load
```

you can see the mac address

edit:
I found one way to do this:
sniff all packages with scapy with the help of function sniff, then filter the packages to get only what you need. There you can use mac address
for example from my project:

```
sniff(prn=self._pkt_callback, store=0)

def _pkt_callback(self, pkt):
    if not self.sniffer_on:
         return
    if Ether not in pkt or pkt[Ether].type != 0x800:
        return
    if pkt[IP].proto != 17: # 17 means UDP package
        return
    if pkt[UDP].dport != 6665:
        return

    print pkt.src, pkt.load    #src is mac address
```