# Obtain MAC Address from Devices using Python

Tags: python, ip-address, mac-address

I'm looking for a way (with python) to obtain the `layer II` address from a device on my local network.  `Layer III` addresses are known.

The goal is to build a script that will poll a databases of IP addresses on regular intervals ensuring that the mac addresses have not changed and if they have, email alerts to myself.

Comment: He's avoiding gratuitous ARP, not checking stuff on the local machine.  Read the question carefully: **from a device on my local network**

Comment: There are many potentially helpful answers here! [How can I get the IP address of eth0 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24196932/3904031)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To answer the question with Python depends on your platform.  I don't have Windows handy, so the following solution works on the Linux box I wrote it on.  A small change to the regular expression will make it work in OS X.

First, you must ping the target.  That will place the target -- as long as it's within your netmask, which it sounds like in this situation it will be -- in your system's ARP cache.  Observe:

```
13:40 jsmith@undertow% ping 97.107.138.15
PING 97.107.138.15 (97.107.138.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 97.107.138.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.25 ms
^C

13:40 jsmith@undertow% arp -n 97.107.138.15
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
97.107.138.15            ether   fe:fd:61:6b:8a:0f   C                     eth0
```

Knowing that, you do a little subprocess magic -- otherwise you're writing ARP cache checking code yourself, and you don't want to do that:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> import re
>>> IP = "1.2.3.4"

>>> # do_ping(IP)
>>> # The time between ping and arp check must be small, as ARP may not cache long

>>> pid = Popen(["arp", "-n", IP], stdout=PIPE)
>>> s = pid.communicate()[0]
>>> mac = re.search(r"(([a-f\d]{1,2}\:){5}[a-f\d]{1,2})", s).groups()[0]
>>> mac
"fe:fd:61:6b:8a:0f"
```

Comment: Ha, that is exactly the answer I was in the middle of writing!

Comment: If you don't have arp (which OpenWRT does not) and have the ip-neighbour package (which can be installed on OpenWRT) then you can use this command to get the value for `pid`:

`pid = Popen(["ip", "neigh", "show", IP], stdout=PIPE)`

Comment: Ran this code on Raspberry Pi Zero.  arp not found, but it's found when I type it into a command terminal

Answer (score 7):

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85577/search-for-host-with-mac-address-using-python) answered not too long ago on this site. As mentioned in the answer chosen by the asker of that question, Python doesn't have a built-in way to do it.  You must either call a system command such as `arp` to get ARP information, or generate your own packets using [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).

**Edit:** An example using Scapy [from their website](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending.html):

> Here is another tool that will
>   constantly monitor all interfaces on a
>   machine and print all ARP request it
>   sees, even on 802.11 frames from a
>   Wi-Fi card in monitor mode. Note the
>   store=0 parameter to sniff() to avoid
>   storing all packets in memory for
>   nothing.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from scapy import *

def arp_monitor_callback(pkt):
    if ARP in pkt and pkt[ARP].op in (1,2): #who-has or is-at
        return pkt.sprintf("%ARP.hwsrc% %ARP.psrc%")

sniff(prn=arp_monitor_callback, filter="arp", store=0)
```

You could also do something similar to the verified answer. See https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/routing.html

```
>>> mac = getmacbyip("10.0.0.1")
>>> mac
'f3:ae:5e:76:31:9b'
```

This is fully cross platform.

Not exactly what you're looking for, but definitely on the right track.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

In Linux sometimems you miss the command line util "arp". A base yocto linux embedded environment image for instance.

An alternative way without the "arp" tool would be to read and parse the file /proc/net/arp:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /proc/net/arp
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.1.1      0x1         0x2         xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx     *        wlan0
192.168.1.33     0x1         0x2         yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy     *        wlan0
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution using scapy, to scan the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet is as follows:

```
from scapy.all import *

ans,unans = arping("192.168.0.0/24", verbose=0)
for s,r in ans:
    print("{} {}".format(r[Ether].src,s[ARP].pdst))
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to monitor ARP spoofers? In this case, all you need is [arpwatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpwatch), available in every well-supplied Linux distribution near you. Download sources here: http://ee.lbl.gov/

Answer (score 2):

for Unix based systems:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import re
import subprocess
arp_out =subprocess.check_output(['arp','-lan'])

re.findall(r"((\w{2,2}\:{0,1}){6})",arp_out)
```

will return list of tuples with macs.
scapy is an amazing tool , but seems to be overkill for this case

Answer (score 1):

an easier way, if on linux:

`print os.system('arp -n ' + str(remoteIP))`

you will get:

```
    Address        HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
    192.168.....   ether   9B:39:15:f2:45:51   C                     wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

General update for Python 3.7. Remark: the option `-n` for `arp` does not provide the arp list on windows systems as provided with certain answers for linux based systems. Use the option `-a` as stated in the answer here.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

pid = Popen(['arp', '-a', ip], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

IP, MAC, var = ((pid.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').split('Type\r\n'))[1]).split('     ')
IP  =  IP.strip(' ')
MAC =  MAC.strip(' ')

if ip == IP:
    print ('Remote Host : %s\n        MAC : %s' % (IP, MAC))
```