# Find mac address on python

Tags: python, linux, mac-address

I have searched for an identifier and I tried to find mac address for any connected device on my server but the problem is that the output returns empty for example

`a = os.popen("arp -a  192.168.6.150 | awk '{print $4}'").readlines()`

a is empty

I'm working on captive portal page for untangle.
I want to get the mac address from ip of device on network.
This code runs on Apache server.

```
from mod_python import apache
from mod_python import util
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting MAC Address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address)

Comment: I think the OP wants to get the MAC address of any device in the network, given its IP address (not the MAC of the machine running the code)

Comment: The solution is here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1750931/2615399

Comment: Is the IP in the same subnet as your server?

Comment: yes the IP in the same subnet, the problem is that all commands runs on terminal but not run on the page

Comment: all arp commands not run on the page

Comment: There are many helpful answers here! [How can I get the IP address of eth0 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24196932/3904031)

Answer (score 4):

The following function returns the mac or `None` if mac is not found.

```
import commands
def getmac(iface):
    mac = commands.getoutput("ifconfig " + iface + "| grep HWaddr | awk '{ print $5 }'")
    if len(mac)==17:
        return mac

getmac('eth0')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import re, uuid


print (' : '.join(re.findall('..', '%012x' % uuid.getnode())))
```

Comment: The original problem is that the code doesn't run when requested from a webpage. It has little to do with the parsing method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use python **scapy** module for the same

```
from scapy.all import *
def get_mac(ip_address):
    responses,unanswered = srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst=ip_address),timeout=2,retry=10)
# return the MAC address from a response
    for s,r in responses:
        return r[Ether].src
    return None
get_mac("192.168.31.14")
```