# How to locate specific mac address using python

Tags: python, mac-address

I want to trigger some functions when specific device connected in my network.

I know my device's mac address.

But I don't know how to locate this device's mac address using python.

Some solutions using shell script, but I want to use python.

Please let me know the solution.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting MAC Address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159137/getting-mac-address)

Comment: @Yoel OP not asking how to get his own mac, Op want when a device is conned to his network he want that device mac address

Answer (score 1):

If you want to locate your local MAC, you can use [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) package.

```
import netifaces
netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')
```

Comment: No, not local MAC address.

Comment: Is this device broadcasting itself or does it at least require DHCP address? See this post too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750803/obtain-mac-address-from-devices-using-python