# Ubuntu Python: "get_mac" function not defined

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I've recently been following through the book, "Black hat python", it's been alright but when I try the `get_mac` function the console spits out an error, specifically:

```
NameError: name 'get_mac' is not defined".
```

I am not sure if this just is a Linux based issue.

**Code:**

```
from scapy.all import *
import os
import sys
import threading
import signal

interface="en1"
target_ip="10.0.0.17"
gateway_ip="10.0.0.138"
packet_count=1000

# set up our interface
conf.iface=interface

# turn off input
conf.verg=0

print"[*] Setting up %s"%interface

gateway_mac=get_mac(gateway_ip)
```

Comment: No such function.  Was it maybe defined earlier in the book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have transcribed only part of the script from the book. The text explains that the `get_mac` function will be defined later on in the exposition.

On page 53, right after the code, the author explains:

> We start by resolving the gateway (1) and target IP (2) address's corresponding MAC addresses using a function called `get_mac` that we'll plumb in shortly.

The function is defined later on page 53, and amounts to

```
def get_mac(ip_address):
    responses, unanswered =
        srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst_ip_address),
            timeout=2, retry=10)
    for s, r in responses:
        return r[Ether].src
    return None
```

This code has multiple problems; I had to fix an indentation error where the first `return` statement was not indented, and of course, you can only `return` once, so the loop and the final `return` are effectively dead code.  Perhaps the author is trying to make sure you are awake.

[The book is available from Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=9MS9BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&lpg=PA52&dq=black+hat+get_mac&source=bl&ots=tYdr0H_I6I&sig=P8_HkydQ4AboPzZabzof9ti5Dfk&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=black%20hat%20get_mac&f=false), so that's what I used.  If they have a different edition or something, maybe yours is slightly different.

Comment: I also notice that you transcribed `conf.verb` (as in *verbose)* incorrectly.

Comment: The `import *` is obviously also poor style.

Answer (score 0):

I just try on my ubuntu 14.04 this code:

```
from uuid import getnode as get_mac
mac = get_mac()
```

All doing excellent.

If you need an arp-address from selected ip try the recipe from this stackoverflow question: [Obtain MAC Address from Devices using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750803/obtain-mac-address-from-devices-using-python)

Comment: That does not work when i insert it into my current code, I receive this error: "TypeError: getnode() takes no arguments (1 given)"

Comment: I add a link to similar question on stackoverflow with another recipe. Try this one.