# how to communicate between client and server?

Tags: python, django, sockets

I want to receive mac address of the clients as soon as they connect to server. For this I have tried sockets but server won't run unless I set a timeout. I want to run sockets the entire time so that I can receive data from client whenever it reaches server.
Basically I have a wi-fi setup and want to keep record of clients using their mac address who are connecting to my wi-fi network. Is there any other way to get their mac address apart from ssh.
my view.py file is as follows, if there is error please notify.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

import os
# Create your views here.
#from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
#import socket, sys

import pickle
import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket ( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM )
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
s.settimeout(3)
try:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    objrcv = pickle.loads ( conn.recv ( 1024 ) )
    ip = objrcv[0]
    mac = objrcv[1]
except:
    print "Can't connect"

def student_detail(request):
    queryset = attendance.objects.filter(mac=mac)
    context ={
        "object_list":queryset,
        "title": "Attendance",

    }
    return render(request, "attendance.html", context)
```

Comment: What do you mean by connect to django server? People never connect to it, they send web requests to it

Comment: I'm setting up  a wi-fi network. I want to get their mac address as soon as they connect to my wi-fi network and display their mac address on django server. Sorry for that....I'm new to django

Comment: Django isn't a server and it never will be. From the [docs for `runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/django-admin/#runserver) - "And that’s how it’s gonna stay. We’re in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers"

Comment: @hugh what about tornado? http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You 'know' the ip address of the connecting client. So you can use this information to obtain more information, e.g. with `arp -n`

```
# your_app/views.py
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from django.shortcuts import render

def mac(request):

    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    proc = Popen(["arp", "-n", ip], stdout=PIPE)
    out = proc.communicate()[0]
    mac = re.search(r"(([a-f\d]{1,2}\:){5}[a-f\d]{1,2})", out).groups()[0]

    return render(request, 'mac.html', {'mac': mac})
```

#### Credits:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581997/469111
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1750931/469111

#### Note:

`arp -n` only gives a result for 'known' entries (`arp -a`). In the situation here it is working because the client request happening *before* the arp lookup.

Comment: there could be around 4000 clients to my server, will this script have any affect on my resource utilization as there will be lots of processes going on besides this

Comment: What do you mean with '4000 clients to my server'? The relevant number here would be how many 'requests per second' you do expect.

Comment: around 500 requests per second

Comment: The mac lookup here should not be the bottleneck. The information comes from the arp table, so it is fast. But serving 500r/s through Django with database queries will need some resources...