# Find a mac adress of an specific IP on the same network

Tags: python, ip, arp

I want to do a function that will find the mac adress of a specific IP that a user will put in the parameter of the function ( The IP have to be on the same network). I want to find this with ARP. I see that I can do this :

macc = get_mac()
return hex(macc)

But the problem is that I want to give a mac adress for a specific IP. How can I do this ?
Thanks You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtain MAC Address from Devices using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750803/obtain-mac-address-from-devices-using-python)