# How to find out how many clients are on a certain address range?

Tags: python, networking, nmap, port-scanning

I tried googling for this but i didnt find anything... I am building a port scanner and i would like to make it so, that i can scan a network range e.g 192.168.2.* and find out how many computers are on that range that are online. Alot like Nmap. I am programming in python. Is this possible in Python?

Comment: Your title is misleading. There is only ever one host per IP address. You seem to be asking about address *ranges.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is **Draft** example that you can start with:

```
import socket

addr_range = "192.168.1.%d"

ip_address_up = []

# Use UDP. 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.settimeout(2.0)

for i in range(1, 254):
    try:
        ip = addr_range % i
        socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)
        ip_address_up.append(ip)
    except socket.herror as ex:
        pass

print ip_address_up
```

or something like this using ICMP ([ping](http://svn.pylucid.net/pylucid/CodeSnippets/ping.py)) rather thank UDP:

```
import socket
import ping

ip_address_up = []

addr_range = "192.168.1.%d"

for i in range(1, 254):       
   try:
       ip = addr_range % i
       delay = ping.do_one(ip, timeout=2)
       ip_address_up.append(ip)
   except (socket.herror, socket.timeout) as ex:
       pass

print ip_address_up
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `python-nmap`. Basic usage:

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.scan(hosts='192.168.2.0/24', arguments='-n -sP -PE -PA21,23,80,3389')
hosts_list = [(x, nm[x]['status']['state']) for x in nm.all_hosts()]
for host, status in hosts_list:
    print('{0}:{1}'.format(host, status))
```

For further reference see http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-nmap

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I would like to know how to make this function by myself.

Comment: Or is it very complicated? I made the portscanner itself, but i am missing the computer detection code.

Comment: Well, how are you scanning the IP? Are you pinging it? Creating a TCP connection?

Comment: By creating a TCP connection.

Comment: By that heuristic - if you managed to create a connection, then the IP is alive.

Comment: I see.. You just gave me an idea. Thanks for all your input!

Comment: How would i go about finding out how many clients are behind an IP-address (like when one is connected through a router)?

Comment: You have no way of figuring that out, unless you try to hack that LAN.

Comment: OK i see. So when i scan an IP and it responds.. Which machine on the LAN is responding ? Or is it the router itself?

Answer (score 0):

Using [raw sockets](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) you can implement something nmap-like. You will probably find that the most informative probes need to be made using specially crafted packets that do "odd" things, compared to normal programming interfaces. It's well worth reading up on the IP/UDP/TCP [RFCs](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/).

Using raw sockets you can generate byte by byte any probing packet of your choosing, with options/configurations set that are normally impossible/hard to do under normal circumstances, but which "trick" a host into revealing a wealth of information.

Answer (score 0):

For IPv4 on local net you can resort to [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) using say [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/), [see related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85577/search-for-host-with-mac-address-using-python).